# Python automating mouse click without 'using' my mouse

Tags: python, automation, pyautogui

I would like to know if there is a way to make automated clicking tasks without making me unable to use the mouse on my pc to do other stuff. I mean, I want to use the pc normally with the main monitor while on the second monitor python would be performing some clicks.

There is any lib that can do this? Or maybe if I use a virtual machine only to run the code and the program to be automated I could use my pc without been affect?

Comment: If you are running your automation code on a virtual machine then you don't need to worry about your code interfering with mouse controls on the machine where you host your VM. What are you trying to automate by the way? If you are working with web pages in a browser then Selenium can do the job without the need of a virtual machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in Loop, while changing input arguments of function. This is one way of doing it inside you Windows. You can define your locations (x,y) on plan. it will keep on doing things inside your VM.

```
import win32api, win32con
def click(x,y):
    win32api.SetCursorPos((x,y))
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN,x,y,0,0)
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP,x,y,0,0)
click(100,100)
```